# D3.js force layout - edge label placement/rotation

Tags: javascript, d3.js, label, force-layout

I'm pretty new with D3.js, and I've been playing around with force layout. One of the things I tried was placing labels on links.

One way of doing it is by appending `svg:text` and manually calculating `translate` & `rotate`, which works fine with straight lines. But, in case when link is a `svg:path` (e.g. arc), this doesn't work as expected. In these cases, `svg:textPath` is suggested solution.

In [this demo](http://bl.ocks.org/mfolnovic/6269308/5c017c0391a8e12db1fc573be3ef8a9bdcb5a117), you can see a simple implementation of adding labels to links through `svg:textPath`. The only problem with it is that, in case when source is positioned to the right of target, text is rendered in opposite direction (from our point of view, it's still correct from path's perspective). My question is, how to deal with this?

The only *"solution"* I came up with is, manually swapping source and target in case described above. [Here](http://bl.ocks.org/mfolnovic/6269308/086c505caa848750ab9916bd48906b4057e6f288), you can see that it *almost* works.

[image]

In state when the swap happens, you can also see arc flipping to other side, which doesn't look right. :(

Comment: You can't specify a text direction for `textPath` -- the text always follows the direction of the path. So the solution you have is the only feasible one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

@LarsKotthoff is correct that the `textPath` has to follow the direction of the path. In this case, the direction of the path defines not only the arc direction, but the attachment of the arrow marker on the end - this makes it tricky to swap directions on the fly, as you have to move the marker too.

The simpler solution (though maybe not the best if you have a large number of links) is to "shadow" the real link path with an invisible path used just for text:

```
var link = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("g.link")
    .data(force.links())
  .enter().append('g')
    .attr('class', 'link');

var linkPath = link.append("svg:path")
    .attr("class", function(d) { return "link " + d.type; })
    .attr("marker-end", function(d) { return "url(#" + d.type + ")"; });

var textPath = link.append("svg:path")
    .attr("id", function(d) { return d.source.index + "_" + d.target.index; })
    .attr("class", "textpath");
```

Now you have a separate path you can manipulate properly. As you noticed, there are two issues - you have to change the path direction, and you have to change the arc direction. It looks like you can do this in the path command string by swapping the `sweep-flag` value ([see docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataMovetoCommands)), so instead of `Arx,ry 0 0,1` you have `Arx,ry 0 0,0`. You can reduce some code duplication by having one function to create path strings:

```
function arcPath(leftHand, d) {
    var start = leftHand ? d.source : d.target,
        end = leftHand ? d.target : d.source,
        dx = end.x - start.x,
        dy = end.y - start.y,
        dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy),
        sweep = leftHand ? 0 : 1;
    return "M" + start.x + "," + start.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr +
        " 0 0," + sweep + " " + end.x + "," + end.y;
}
```

Then you can update the link path and the text path separately:

```
linkPath.attr("d", function(d) {
    return arcPath(false, d);
});

textPath.attr("d", function(d) {
    return arcPath(d.source.x < d.target.x, d);
});
```

See working code: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/VYaGg/2/

Comment: It's not advisable to create more than one node per data element in a data join.  It will result in unexpected behavior if/when you update the data and do the join a second time.  Here's some more details about why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808320/can-enter-selection-be-reused-after-append-insert

Comment: Point taken, but it's perfectly acceptable to do this if you aren't planning to dynamically update the data later - often the case with network graphs, and the OP didn't mention updates. I'll update my answer, but I don't think the original approach was incorrect, and I think it's poor form to downvote just because you don't like the approach.

Comment: Not sure if it's poor form or not. I'm still trying to get a feel for  voting in SO. My reasoning here was that, while you're right that doing this technically works in a limited example, it is encouraging a coding practice that will not work in general.  My experience is that data joining is one of the most widely misunderstood parts of d3 by people new to the library, so I feel that answers should be especially rigorous about showing data joining techniques that encourage and promote the general understanding of such a fundamental mechanism.  Just my opinion, of course.

Comment: Well, to downvote or not is up to you, and I can see your point - I guess the disagreement is whether my original response was truly promoting poor practice, or whether it was perfectly reasonable within a limited scope. Either way, it's generally appreciated if you drop the downvote when an answer is updated in response to your suggestion (as it's no longer objectionable).

Comment: Another way of putting it: Generally, I might downvote for outright poor practice, but not for the lack of best practice (unless the OP was specifically asking for best practice).

Comment: can someone explain how this is an anti pattern. the data corresponds to "link" which is ONE svg:g. Inside we can have the two paths. It is still corresponding to only one group element per data item.

Comment: This question is pretty old, but I think I updated it to avoid the anti-pattern originally discussed.