# d3 Force Directed Layout - Multiple Edge Labels

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, label, force-layout

Is it possible to have multiple labels on an edge in a d3 force-directed layout?

I'm looking to add a label nearest to Node A, one in the middle and one nearest Node B (nodes can have their own labels):

[ NodeA ]--label1-----------------------------label2-----------------------------label3--[ NodeB ]

Comment: There's no limit on how many labels you can add. Just add more `text` elements.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23470330/adding-label-to-the-links-in-d3-force-directed-graph) may help you.