# d3 / React / Hooks - Updates do not clean up old rects and Groups

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, react-hooks

I am working on a realtime updating bar chart implementation using d3 with React and Hooks.

Though the new 'g' groups and `rect`s do get added to the svg, the old groups do not seem to be getting cleared up. So, the rects just get added on top of the old rects, as do the axis groups.

I am using the .join() API so I shouldn't need to do manually clean up with exit.remove() right? I am completely new to d3 so forgive the uncertainty.

app:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import Chart from './Chart';

function useInterval(callback, delay) {
  const savedCallback = useRef();

  // Remember the latest callback.
  useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback;
  }, [callback]);

  // Set up the interval.
  useEffect(() => {
    function tick() {
      savedCallback.current();
    }
    if (delay !== null) {
      let id = setInterval(tick, delay);
      return () => clearInterval(id);
    }
  }, [delay]);
}

function App() {
  const [menu, setMenu] = useState([]);

  const db = firebase.firestore();

  useEffect(() => {
    db.collection('dishes')
      .get()
      .then((res) => {
        let data = [];
        for (let doc of res.docs) {
          data.push(doc.data());
        }
        setMenu(data);
      });
  }, []);

  useInterval(() => {
    let newMenu = [];
    newMenu = [...menu];

    if (newMenu[0] && newMenu[0].hasOwnProperty('orders')) {

      newMenu[0].orders += 50;

      setMenu(newMenu);
    }
  }, 3000);

  return (
    <div className="App">{menu.length > 0 ? <Chart data={menu} /> : null}</div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Chart component:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import * as d3 from 'd3';

const Chart = ({ data }) => {
  const height = 600;

  // Generate a ref instance
  const svgRef = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    const svg = d3.select(svgRef.current);

    const margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 100, left: 100 };
    const graphWidth = 600 - margin.left - margin.right;
    const graphHeight = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    // Find the maximum order value
    const max = d3.max(data, (d) => d.orders);

    // Establish the y scale
    // i.e., map my max value to the pixel max value ratio
    const y = d3
      .scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, max * 1.25])
      .range([graphHeight, 0]);

    // Calculates width and coordinates for each bar
    // Can add padding here
    const x = d3
      .scaleBand()
      .domain(data.map((item) => item.name))
      .range([0, graphHeight])
      .padding(0.25);

    const graph = svg
      .append('g')
      .attr('width', graphWidth)
      .attr('height', graphWidth)
      .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`);

    //   Creat axis groups for legends and labels
    const xAxisGroup = graph
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', `translate(0,${graphHeight})`);
    const yAxisGroup = graph.append('g');

    // Append the graph to the DOM
    graph
      .selectAll('rect')
      .data(data, (entry, i) => entry)
      .join(
        (enter) => enter.append('rect'),
        (update) => update.append('class', 'new'),
        (exit) => exit.remove()
      )
      .transition()
      .duration(300)
      .attr('width', x.bandwidth)
      .attr('height', (d) => graphHeight - y(d.orders))
      .attr('fill', 'orange')
      .attr('x', (d) => x(d.name))
      .attr('y', (d) => y(d.orders));

    //  Create the axes
    const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x);
    const yAxis = d3
      .axisLeft(y)
      //   .ticks(3)
      .tickFormat((d) => d + ' orders');

    // Append the axes to the graph
    xAxisGroup.call(xAxis);
    yAxisGroup.call(yAxis);

    xAxisGroup
      .selectAll('text')
      .attr('transform', 'rotate(-40)')
      .attr('text-anchor', 'end');
  }, [data]);

  return (
    <div>
      <svg ref={svgRef} height={height} width="600" />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Chart;
```

Comment: You are doing a join in a fresh `g` every time you run `useEffect` - there are no rects to exit, because you aren't selecting the existing rects. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61314519/7106086)

Comment: Thank you Andrew. I will take a look.